# Деепричастия совершенного вида на а/я

Tags: деепричастия

Некоторые деепричастия сов. вида образуются с помощью суффикса "а/я" (нахмуря). Можно ли употреблять форму "покрестя" (от слова "крестить")

Answer (score 1):

Есть отчетливые правила того, как образовываются формы деепричастия совершенного вида в зависимости от букв, которыми заканчивается корень, а также других каких-то параметров. Эти правила знает любой носитель (не в формализованном виде, конечно). Если носитель услышит впервые глагол, то он будет знать, как образовывать все его формы. Например, сходу видно, что если корень заканчивается на ‟р”, то деепричастие образовывается добавлением к корню ‟я” (курить — куря, бурить — буря и т.д.). ‟Покрестив” образовывается не от ‟крестить”, так как слово ‟крестить” вообще несовершенного вида и, следовательно, не имеет формы деепричастия совершенного вида. ‟Покрестив” образовывается от ‟покрестить”. ‟Нахмуря” образовывается от глагола ‟нахмурить”. Я вижу, что глаголы совершенного вида, которые заканчиваются на ‟р”, образуют форму деепричастия совершенного вида двумя способами: как
добавляя к корню ‟ив”, так и добавляя ‟я”: скурить сигару — скуря сигару — скурив сигару, пожарить блины — пожаря блины — пожарив блины. Не все слова с ‟я” считаются нормой — ‟сваря суп”, например.
Возвращаясь к вашему вопросу, если нет ‟р” на конце у глаголов совершенного вида, то деепричастия образуются только одним способом (могу ошибаться, так как не знаком с формализацией данной темы), в вашем случае с добавлением ‟ив” — покрестив.
Вот пара примеров глаголов совершенного вида на ‟ить”: возместить ущерб — возместив ущерб (даже в разговорной речи никто не скажет ‟возместя ущерб”), подсадить его — подсадив его (даже в разговорной речи никто не скажет ‟подсадя его”), отрастить бороду — отрастив бороду (даже в разговорной речи никто не скажет ‟отрастя бороду”).

Answer (score 0):

Если я не ошибаюсь, деепричастия совершенного вида с суффиксами *-а-*, *-я-* — устаревающие и правильнее говорить: нахмурив, построив, покрестив. (Исключение: деепричастия *придя, дойдя* и прочие от совершенных глаголов *-йти*, потому что "пришедши" и аналогичные выглядят ещё более устаревшими).